# ViewPager returns OOM in setImageResource

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Setting drawable in viewpager onPageselected causes OOM.

```
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(final int position) {
                final View[] images = new View[]{image1, image2, image3, image4, image5};
                final int[] imageIds = new int[] {R.drawable.image1, R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3, R.drawable.image4, R.drawable.image5};
                if(position < images.length && images[position].getBackground() == null) {
                    ((ImageView)images[position]).setImageResource(imageIds[position]); //crashes with OOM for most devices, some devices it works
                }
}
```

Crash Log:

```
1   dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray  Native Method
2   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset    Native Method
3   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream BitmapFactory.java, line 856
4   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream BitmapFactory.java, line 675
5   android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream Drawable.java, line 2230
```

Comment: How big are your images?

Comment: the max is 150k

Comment: I suggest you first try to use much smaller images just to see if the images are causing the crash (even though 150k seems very reasonable). Another thing worth trying is using an image caching library.